# Python shell is not restarting after running a module

Tags: python, shell, module, restart

For some reason my python shell is not restarting when I run a module.  I feel like I've tried everything.  I have opened, and created new files through the shell.  I have reinstalled python.  I have restarted my machine. etc. etc.

The shell does work when I write a function directly into it, so it's not a problem with the shell itself.  When I "run module" in a .py file, it toggles to the shell but it doesn't have the "restart" message as it did before.  So, running functions in .py files obviously doesn't work...

Has anyone else experienced this? Any ideas?

I'm using the python 3.4.6 shell for windows 64 bit...I was using 3.4.3 before but I thought upgrading might help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'running a module' and 'restarting the Python shell'? So, I assume that you are using a Python shell/console instead of an IPython console?

Comment: I mean that within a .py file when you click on "run module" it only toggles to the shell, the shell does not have a "restart" as it had before...and this was also happening in 3.4.3 so I don't think the upgrade is the issue...

Comment: Okay, it seems that you are using a specific editor. Maybe you could add that to the tags?

Comment: Sure - I'm using IDLE version 3.6.4 (64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

I have personally never experienced this, however, if this has been happening AS SOON AS you upgraded to the 3.4.6 python shell, the existing scripts may be affecting the .py scripts used to run the python shell. I don't know  if this helps but maybe go back to 3.4.3 or download the 3.6.4 version of python.

https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  This issue was occurring in 3.4.3 as well!